# Unexpected error in a shell script : "Unexpected keyword `from` ". Can't locate the mistake

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a shell script that will connect with database and retrieve the records. But when I exceute it, it gives me the error as: Unexpected keyword `from`. Can anyone please suggest me what mistake I am doing?
The code I have done is as given below:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Script and Log Location
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCRIPTHOME=/opt/psoft/scripts
SCRIPTINPUT=/opt/psoft/scripts/tac/input
SCRIPTLOG=/opt/psoft/scripts/tac/log
SCRIPTOUTPUT=/opt/psoft/scripts/tac/output
SCRIPTNOTPROCESSED=/opt/psoft/scripts/tac/notprocessed

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Oracle Environment
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/9.2.0
export TNS_ADMIN=/var/opt/oracle/admin/network
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$HOME/scripts:.

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Program
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

incno=$1;
if test ${#incno} -lt 6 
then
    echo "Please provide 6 digit incident no";
    echo "TAC script has not been run";
    exit;
fi; 

cd ${SCRIPTINPUT}
if test -e *.csv 
then
    #cd ${SCRIPTINPUT}      
    for f in *.csv
    do
        dos2unix $f $f # To remove control M characters in the input file
        echo " $f - Control M characters removed sucessfully " >> input.log
    done
    echo " Control M characters present in all files in input folder has been removed " >>input.log


    cd ${SCRIPTINPUT}
    for INP in *.csv
    do  
        log_file="${SCRIPTLOG}/${INP}.log"
        # To check if input file for Taccode or Not
        cd ${SCRIPTINPUT}

            echo "Taccode to be executed for the file $INP"
            count=0;
            while read line
            do
                pcode=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f "1"`
                tcode=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f "2"`

                cpcode=${#pcode}
                ctcode=${#tcode}
                #cpcode=`echo ${pcode} | grep -oE [[:digit:]] | wc -l`
                #ctcode=`echo ${tcode} | grep -oE [[:digit:]] | wc -l`

                if test $cpcode -eq 5 
                then
                    DBRESULT=`sqlplus sprint2/sh3rl0ck@SPRXP03 

                    select * from mytable where productcode='10130' AND taccode='35710100';
                    quit;`

                    echo "Hello $count:$pcode:$tcode:$DBRESULT"

                    #here the database result should be checked for errors

                    if test $? -ne 0
                    then
                        echo "Query execution failed.Check ${log_file} file for errors!"
                        mv ${SCRIPTINPUT}/$INP ${SCRIPTNOTPROCESSED}
                        exit;   
                    else
                        count=$(expr $count + 1)
                        echo "Record No:${count} ${pcode}:${tcode}" >>${log_file}
                    fi;
                else
                    echo "Problem with product code or tac code. Check log file for errors"
                    echo "Record No:${count} ${pcode}:${tcode}:" >>${log_file}
                    mv ${SCRIPTINPUT}/$INP ${SCRIPTNOTPROCESSED}
                    exit;
                fi;
            done <${INP}   #end file reading while loop

            echo "Script excution succeeded" >>${log_file}
            echo "${count} records inserted"
            echo "Script excution succeeded";
    done #end outer for loop
else
    echo "No csv files found in input directory. -TAC script has not been run."
fi;
```

Comment: Pasting your script to http://shellcheck.net/ would helpfully have indicated the source of the error, though the actual error message is not completely candid.

Comment: I edited out what seemed to be obvious copy/paste errors.  Please review the edit to make sure I didn't remove anything significant.

Comment: I wish http://shellcheck.net/ would also warn about explicitly examining `$?`, or doing `cd` into the same directory umpteen times.  These are mainly stylistic issues, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to put your sqlplus command all on one line

```
DBRESULT=`sqlplus sprint2/sh3rl0ck@SPRXP03 select * from mytable where productcode='10130' AND taccode='35710100'; quit;`
```

or include explicit line breaks

```
DBRESULT=`sqlplus sprint2/sh3rl0ck@SPRXP03 \
    select * from mytable where productcode='10130' AND taccode='35710100'; \
    quit;`
```

Comment: Additionally, you need to escape the `*` with a backslash, or (much better) quote the SQL properly. Also, there is a very good reason `$(command)` is strongly recommended over `\`command\``.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `sqlplus` doesn't support inline sql statement. The only commandline support it has is to run a sql script using `@`. The viable solution to your problem is to use heredoc.

You can do something like:

```
DBRESULT=$(sqlplus sprint2/sh3rl0ck@SPRXP03 <<-SQL
    select * from mytable where productcode='10130' AND taccode='35710100';
    exit;
SQL
)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. Code is working.Can you tell me whether there any way to make a persistance databse connection. Fire multiple queries and then close a connection?

Comment: There is a way using 2 pipes. And it's quite simple and easy than you'd expect.